# Salary Range Determination When Given Percentiles

Tags: distributions

Can one determine an accurate salary range (minimum, mid and maximum) if only provided the 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles?

Comment: It seems the 50th percentile would be a good estimate for the middle of the salary rage. Beyond that, do you know the distribution from which the data came? (Eg, they can't be normal because a salary cannot be $-\infty$.)

Comment: @Gung certainly the parent distribution can be Normal: it will work perfectly fine provided the chance of an unrealistic salary is negligible.  However, it is rare that any set of salary data looks like a sample of a Normal distribution.

Comment: It can't be exactly normal, since it's positive and all normals have non-zero probability of being negative. It might be a distribution that's well-approximated by a normal, but in practice salaries are typically pretty right skew.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're after a sample range (there's typically no defined upper limit on populations of salaries, except in some particular contexts).

In general there's no hope of *accurately* estimating a range from those 3 quantiles.

In some very particular situations there might be additional information that could allow you to get some idea, but I am having difficulty envisioning many situations that would give enough information to *accurately* estimate the sample range that wouldn't also give you the data from which you could simply calculate it.